# Node.js request module getting ETIMEDOUT and ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, sockets, asynchronous, request, httprequest

I'm crawling a lot of links with the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module in parallel with combination of the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module.

I'm noticing alot of `ETIMEDOUT` and `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` errors although the links are reachable and respond fairly quickly using chrome.

I've limit the `maxSockets` to 2 and the `timeout` to 10000 in the request options.
I'm using `async.filterLimit()` with a limit of 2 to even cut down the parallelism to 2 request each time.
So I have 2 sockets, 2 request, and a timeout of 10 seconds to wait for headers response from the server yet I get these errors.

Here;s request configuration I use:

```
{
    ...
    pool: {
        maxSockets: 2
    },
    timeout: 10000
    ,
    time: true
    ...
}
```

Here's the snippet of code I use to fecth links:

```
var self = this;
async.filterLimit(resources, 2, function(resource, callback) {
    request({
        uri: resource.uri
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            ...
        } else {
            self.emit('error', resource, error);
        }
        callback(...);
    })
}, function(result) {
    callback(null, result);
});
```

I listened to the error event and I see whenever the error code is `ETIMEDOUT` the connect object is either true/false so sometimes it's a connection timeout and sometimes it's not (according to request docs)

**UPDATE:**
I decided to boost up the `maxSockets` to `Infinity` so no connection will be hangup due to lack of available sockets:

```
pool: {
    maxSockets: Infinity
}
```

In-order to control the bandwidth I implemented a `requestLoop` method that handle the request with a `maxAttemps` and `retryDelay` parameters to control the requests:

```
async.filterLimit(resources, 10, function(resource, callback) {
    self.requestLoop({
        uri: resource.uri
    }, 100, 5000, function (error, response, body) {
            var fetched = false;
            if (!error) {
                ...
            } else {
                ....
            }
            callback(...);
        });
}, function(result) {
    callback(null, result);
});
```

Implementation of requestLoop:

```
requestLoop = function(options, attemptsLeft, retryDelay, callback, lastError) {
    var self = this;
    if (attemptsLeft <= 0) {
        callback((lastError != null ? lastError : new Error('...')));
    } else {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            var recoverableErrors = ['ESOCKETTIMEDOUT', 'ETIMEDOUT', 'ECONNRESET', 'ECONNREFUSED'];
            var e;
            if ((error && _.contains(recoverableErrors, error.code)) || (response && (500 <= response.statusCode && response.statusCode < 600))) {
                e = error ? new Error('...');
                e.code = error ? error.code : response.statusCode;
                setTimeout((function () {
                    self.requestLoop(options, --attemptsLeft, retryDelay, callback, e);
                }), retryDelay);
            } else if (!error && (200 <= response.statusCode && response.statusCode < 300)) {
                callback(null, response, body);
            } else if (error) {
                e = new Error('...');
                e.code = error.code;
                callback(e);
            } else {
                e = new Error('...');
                e.code = response.statusCode;
                callback(e);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

So this to sum it up:
- Boosted `maxSockets` to `Infinity` to try overcome timeout error of sockets connection
- Implemnted `requestLoop` method to control failed request and `maxAttemps` as well as `retryDelay` of such requests
- Also there's maxium number of concurrent request set by the number passed to `async.filterLimit`

I want to note that I've also played with the settings of everything here in-order to get errors free crawling but so far attempts failed as-well.

Still looking for help about solving this problem.

**UPDATE2:**
I've decided to drop async.filterLimit and make my own limit mechanism.
I just have 3 variables to help me achieve this:
`pendingRequests` - a request array which will hold all requests (will explain later)
`activeRequests` - number of active requests
`maxConcurrentRequests` - number of maximum allowed concurrent requests

into the pendingRequests array, i push a complex object containing a reference to the requestLoop function as well as arguments array containing the arguments to be passed to the loop function:

```
self.pendingRequests.push({
    "arguments": [{
        uri: resource.uri.toString()
    }, self.maxAttempts, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            if (self.policyChecker.isMimeTypeAllowed((response.headers['content-type'] || '').split(';')[0]) &&
                self.policyChecker.isFileSizeAllowed(body)) {
                self.totalBytesFetched += body.length;
                resource.content = self.decodeBuffer(body, response.headers["content-type"] || '', resource);
                callback(null, resource);
            } else {
                self.fetchedUris.splice(self.fetchedUris.indexOf(resource.uri.toString()), 1);
                callback(new Error('Fetch failed because a mime-type is not allowed or file size is bigger than permited'));
            }
        } else {
            self.fetchedUris.splice(self.fetchedUris.indexOf(resource.uri.toString()), 1);
            callback(error);
        }
        self.activeRequests--;
        self.runRequest();
    }],
    "function": self.requestLoop
});
self.runRequest();
```

You'' notice the call to `runRequest()` at the end.
This function job is to manage the requests and fire requests when it can while keeping the maximum `activeRequests` under the limit of `maxConcurrentRequests`:

```
var self = this;
process.nextTick(function() {
    var next;
    if (!self.pendingRequests.length || self.activeRequests >= self.maxConcurrentRequests) {
        return;
    }
    self.activeRequests++;
    next = self.pendingRequests.shift();
    next["function"].apply(self, next["arguments"]);
    self.runRequest();
});
```

This should solve any Timeouts errors, through my testings tho, I've still noticed some timeouts in specific websites I've tested this on. I can't be 100% sure about this, but I'm thinking it's due to the nature of the website backing http-server limiting a user requests to a maximum by doing an ip-checking and as a result returning some HTTP 400 messages to prevent a possible 'attack' on the server.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out @Jorayen?

Comment: @DvideBy0 Updated a solution

Comment: I found the issue with my code was slightly different. It appears that setting a timeout in my code wasn't respected as far as the underlying socket was concerned. I had to wait for the socket event (see below)

Comment: .on('socket', function(socket) {
            socket.setTimeout(30000);
            socket.on('timeout', function() {
              request.abort();
              logger.error('request timed out after 30 seconds');
            });
          })

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js GET Request ETIMEDOUT & ESOCKETTIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320578/node-js-get-request-etimedout-esockettimedout)

Answer (score 46):

Edit: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/37946324/744276

By default, Node has [4 workers to resolve DNS queries](http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/threadpool.html). If your DNS query takes long-ish time, requests will block on the DNS phase, and the symptom is exactly `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` or `ETIMEDOUT`.

Try increasing your uv thread pool size:

```
export UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=128
node ...
```

or in `index.js` (or wherever your entry point is):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 128;

function main() {
   ...
}
```

Edit 1: [I also wrote a blog post](https://eng.uber.com/denial-by-dns/) about it.

Edit 2: if queries are non-unique, you may want to use a cache, like [nscd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd).

Comment: thanks for the helpful addition to this topic, I've yet to tested what you've suggested but that's good to know none the less. I will also report result as soon as I'll have a free time to do so :)

Comment: What I've read about UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE suggests that this is most important for blocking io (such as disk access) but will not matter for non-blocking io (such asnetwork access).

Comment: That's correct, except DNS resolution is also blocking, due to how `getaddrinfo(3)` works.

Answer (score 3):

I found if there are too many async requests, then ESOCKETTIMEDOUT exception happens in linux. The workaround I've found is doing this:

setting this options to request(): 

`agent: false, pool: {maxSockets: 100}`

Notice that after that, the timeout can be lying so you might need to increase it.

Comment: First of all, this worked for me since I was downloading a few hundred small files which caused this bug. Secondly, what are the downsides of increasing the number of sockets? Will they be automatically closed at some point?